# How to extract text between 2 unique phrases and put into ordered list using python?

Tags: python, parsing, text, extract

I have a text file with a lot of lines in it and there are multiple instances of the phrase alpha and bravo, id like to extract everything in between those phrases and have it put into a list in a new text file.
For example, say the source.txt file read

```
<ul class="_539vh _4j13h"><li class="_cx1ua"><div class="_6jvgy">
<div class="_9tu8m"><a class="_5lote _pfo25 _vbtk2" href="/dog/" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;">
<img class="_a012k" src=""></a>
<div class="_mmgca"><div class="_gzjax"><a class="_4zhc5 notranslate _j7lfh" title="dog" href="/cat/">cat</a></div>
```

In this case alpha would be href="/ and bravo would be /" and I would want the list produced to read something like

```
dog
cat
```

How would i be able to do this, I am very new to coding.

One code I found online and tried so far is

```
inFile = open("source.txt")
outFile = open("List.txt", "w")
buffer = []
keepCurrentSet = True
for line in inFile:
    buffer.append(line)
    if line.startswith('href="/'):
        #href="/ starts a new data set
        if keepCurrentSet:
            outFile.write("".join(buffer))
        #now reset our state
        keepCurrentSet = False
        buffer = []
    elif line.startswith('/"'):
        keepCurrentSet = True
inFile.close()
outFile.close()
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your attempts and what problems did you have.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 The Community bot must post a message like this :P. Why don't they automate it. The bot rejected my legitimate edit the other day.

Comment: I added what i tried, but that code only gave me an empty text file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

with open('old','r') as f1, open('new','w') as f2:
    for line in f1:
        for a in re.findall(r'(alpha)(.*?)(bravo)',line):
            f2.write(a[1].strip()+'\n')
```

Comment: Include the text file in the question? Because this works for the text you have provided in the question.

Comment: I made it more clear, not sure if the change would affect the code.

Comment: @user3599811 Its invalid HTML. It doesn't contains the closing tags. You should not parse HTML with regex. Use BeautifulSoup. Try yourself and then post the code and errors if you cant.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is using `.startswith()` - maybe none of your lines (defined by the newline character) start with `'alpha'`.

I'd change your loop statement like this:

```
for line in inFile:
    if 'alpha' in line:
        line = line.replace('alpha', '')
        line = line.replace('bravo', '')
        outFile.write(line)
```